# Adding Dropbox chooser using ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, dropbox

I am trying to integrate **Dropbox chooser** into my **ember application**. This is the snippet that is generated by [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="XXXXXXXXXXX"></script>

<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" id="db-chooser"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
        function(e) {
            alert("Here's the chosen file: " + e.files[0].link)
        }, false);
</script>
```

This is how I tried to implement it in ember.

Included `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="XXXXXXXXXXX"></script>` in the application layout file.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#ember-app',

  customEvents: {
    DbxChooserSuccess: "DbxChooserSuccess"
  },

)};

App.TestView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: "test_view",

  tagName: "li",

  testAction: function(e) {
    alert("DbxChooserSuccess event triggered");

  }

});

//test_view.js.hjs
<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" id="db-chooser" {{action "testAction" on="DbxChooserSuccess" target="view"}}/>
```

This does not work. My question is how can we **add custom event listeners** to html **elements** in ember?

Comment: Ember is only aware of events happening inside the `body` since this is where ember hooks in to do event delegation, does you dropbox snippet live inside the body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the Dropbox Chooser directly through javascript (halfway down the page of [the chooser documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser))

javascript:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  dropboxChooser: function() {

    Dropbox.choose({
      linkType: "direct",
      multiselect: false,
      success: function(files) {
                // Required. Called when a user selects an item in the Chooser
                alert("Here's the file link:" + files[0].link);
      },
      cancel:  function() {}
    });
  }
});
```

template:

```
<button {{action dropboxChooser}}>Choose Dropbox File</button>
```

[Sort of functional JSBin (no valid `data-app-key`)](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/72/edit)